# Host Artifacts from VS Team Services to Stash/Git or direct integration to Chef

Tags: git, msbuild, chef-infra, azure-devops

I would like to build my Artifacts using VSTS and use chef to deploy new artifacts to the windows server. what would be the best approach for this pipeline. 
Does VSTS offer any pipeline to accomplish this?
Do we need any third party software integration?

I am using VS-TS online

Comment: The VSTS Build service has a Chef task you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chef task in [VSTS-Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Chef) you can try with. However, since this task is still in preview, you need to download it and remove the "preview" visibility from task.josn and then upload it to VSTS via [tfx-cli](http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2015/10/05/how-do-i-upload-a-custom-task-for-build).

More information for your reference: [Release Management with VSTS & integration with Azure, Chef and Octopus Deploy](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDaysOnline/UK-TechDays-Online-2016/Release-Management-with-VSTS--integration-with-Azure--Chef-Deployment).